# How can I get the equivalent of Rails.env.production? in application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I basically want to have the environment check done in javascript only, so I don't have to litter my view files with Rails.env.production? checks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way to do this I believe is to set a javascript variable to the value of Rails.env and then add a method in `application.js` to check it. The best place is probably in your layout so in `app/views/layouts/my_layout.html.erb` something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var rails_env = '<%= Rails.env %>';
</script>
```

Which you can then use in your javascript code.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more bulletproof to set `window.rails_env` instead?

Comment: @Magne, I mean using window object as a namespace, to ensure the global scope, i.e. `window.rails_env = '<%= Rails.env %>';`

Comment: @unclenorton : Yes, I know, but why would it be more bulletproof?

Answer (score 5):

I just learned that putting JS in HTML files is a bad idea for lots of reasons, and one should never need to do so.

So, the best way to solve this would be to do this:

In your view (.erb) file:

```
<div id="RAILS_ENV_CONSTANT" style="display:none"><%= Rails.env %></div>
```

At the top of your application.js file:

```
var RAILS_ENV = $('#RAILS_ENV_CONSTANT').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of introducing a new variable, ie `var rails_env = '<%= Rails.env %>'` because it pollutes the global namespace.  Will all JS files need this variable? Or all JS functions?

I would use something similar to @Magne, but instead of creating a hidden div, I'd just apply it to the body tag:

`<body data-rails-env="<%= Rails.env %>">`

Or in HAML (You are using HAML, right?!)

`%body{ "data-rails-env" => Rails.env }`

Then any script can pick it up:

`$("body").data("rails-env")`

Comment: So don't pollute the global namespace. Do what I've lately been doing and stash it in an `Env` class.

Comment: I kind of prefer doing `Env.rails` or something rather than calling `$("body").data("rails-env")` all the time, as it will cut down on duplication. Also, `Env` would be a nice place to store other environment info, kind of like the `Rails` object in Rails. Or at least that's what I was thinking when I started doing this.

Comment: BTW, I like the idea of using a `data` attribute instead of a hidden `<div>`. Come to think of it, a `<meta>` element might be even better.

Answer (score 0):

no you cant check in your JS because JS is not serversided. the onliest way is to generate a JS file in relation to the environment nad include it or make an variable from the template